# Casting live mp4 stream of iPhone's camera to Google Chromecast

Tags: ios, google-cast

I have an application that is capturing video camera input and streaming it into mp4

I have an another application that is passing the first application's URL to a Chromecast device using this code

```
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation = [[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:@"rtsp://192.168.5.159" streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeLive contentType:@"video/mp4" metadata:metadata streamDuration:0 customData:nil];
//cast video [_mediaControlChannel loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:TRUE playPosition:0];
```

The Chromecast device tries to play the stream but immediately fails.

Answer (score 0):

I see "rtsp" as the streaming protocol. You need to serve that using http for chromecast to be able to play that.

Comment: Thanks I will try it using HTTP when I will get some time for that. Will get back once I've got any result...